# Overview work on radio solitons?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas, solitons

I've heard about solitons in dense mediums (water), sparse mediums (acoustic) and optical fiber.

But I can't find a good overview work on solitons in radio spectrum. Something like generating EM solitons with a peculiar antenna setup. It seems like an obvious thing for people to be working on, but looks like I just lack proper terminology to google it. Is there something that can be recommended, preferably with an experimental setup described?

Comment: IEEE is your friend, see https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?action=search&newsearch=true&matchBoolean=true&queryText=(%22Full%20Text%20.AND.%20Metadata%22:soliton%20transmission%20line%20varactor)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like substituting "radio" for "varactor" does get better results.

Comment: varactors (ie., back-biased diodes) give the "cheapest" mass-producible and re-producible non-linearity...